# how to change the rich text editor to normal text editor in hmc

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am a newbie to SAP Hybris. I have a scenario where I need to change the product description from rich text editor to normal text editor in hmc.
Default we can see the rich text editor in hmc for the description field

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
<section name="product.descriptions">
              <listlayout>
                 <attribute name="description">
                    <wysiwygeditor/>
                 </attribute>
                 <attribute name="unit"/>
              </listlayout>
           </section>
```

to

```
      <section name="product.descriptions" mode="replace">
              <listlayout>
                 <attribute name="description"/>
                 <attribute name="unit"/>
              </listlayout>
           </section>
```

in your core extension hmc.xml

Just remove `<wysiwygeditor/>` or you can use normal `<textareaeditor/>`.

For Example : yourcoreextension -> hmc -> resource -> hmc.xml

put this config ->

```
<type name="Product" mode="append">
  <organizer>
    <editor mode="append"> 
      <tab name="tab.product.properties" position="1" mode="append">
        <section name="product.descriptions" mode="replace">
              <listlayout>
                 <attribute name="description"/>                                      
                 <attribute name="unit"/>
              </listlayout>
           </section>
      </tab>
     </editor>
  </organizer>
</type>
```